# cannot set property of null javascript error

Tags: javascript, angularjs, typescript

I don't understand why am i getting this Error. Can someone please help. 
I can successfully get the snapshot value. only when i m trying to assign true/false to this.user_data. I am getting this error: Cannot set property 'user_data' of null

```
public user_data = false;


constructor(public afAuth: AngularFireAuth, public afDb: AngularFireDatabase)   {

  }


check_user_exists(number: string){

    const dats = firebase.database().ref('users');

     dats.orderByChild('number').equalTo(number).once("value", function(snapshot){



        if(snapshot.val() !== null){

            this.user_data = true;
            console.log(this.user_data);


        } else {

            this.user_data = false;
            console.log(this.user_data);

        }


    });



}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"this" is not what you think it is, in javascript `this` isn't the same as in some other languages.

To make your code work:

```
 (snapshot) => { 
 // ...
});
```

instead of

```
function (snapshot) { ... }
```

I'd suggest taking the time to dig deep on what "[this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this)" is though

Comment: thxx for your answer... come from a php background...your suggestion works! but still i gotta look deep into how to use this though.. that link is useful..thx again :D